# Uber Business Account not getting charged through Uber API anymore

Tags: uber-api

Our application uses Uber API to book rides for users and charge an Uber Business Account for these rides. But a few weeks back, we received an error - **The rider's payment method is invalid and they must update their billing info.**. So, we updated the access token and payment method id for this rider, and rides were getting booked again. But they are not showing up in Uber Business Account anymore and only showing up in rider's personal account. Got it checked that none of the payment methods of these accounts have been revoked due to too many cancellations.

Also, while a ride is booked through Uber's native app from this rider's account, by choosing Business profile, the ride gets reflected in trips taken in Business Account.

It shows Business Profile selected in Uber's native app, when we book a ride through Uber API and pass payment method of Business Account, but the ride isn't reflected in Business Account.

Here is the request we are making -

```
Endpoint - https://api.uber.com/v1/requests
Headers - Authorization:Bearer <access token>
                 Content-Type:application/json
Body - {
         "start_latitude": 30.7056149,
         "start_longitude": 76.6895002,
         "end_latitude": 30.7069548,
         "end_longitude": 76.7080182,
         "payment_method_id": "<payment method id for Business Account>",
         "expense_memo": "Checking Ride on Business Account"
       }
```

The response we are getting -

```
Body -
       {
         "status": "processing",
         "product_id": "<uber product id>",
         "request_id": "<uber ride request id>",
         "driver": null,
         "eta": null,
         "location": null,
         "vehicle": null,
         "surge_multiplier": 1,
         "shared": false
       }
```

Is there something that has changed in taking rides through Business Profile using Uber API?